# Checkbox checked input required , if checkbox is unchecked input not required

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked" id="check" onclick="unlocking()">
    <label for="checkbox">If checked</label>
    <fieldset id="unlock" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="Name" id="inside" required>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="email" id="inside" required>
        <input type="text" name="Adress" value="Adress" id="inside" required>
      </fieldset>
```

And this is my js with the function to hide and show the fieldset.

```
    function unlocking() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("check")
      var form = document.getElementById("unlock")

      if(checkBox.checked) {
       form.style.display="block";
      }else {
       form.style.display="none";
     }
    }
```

If the fieldset is show i want the input to be required and if not just to skip it.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each child and set its `required` attribute to either `true` or `false` depending on if the checkbox is checked or not, like so:

```
for (child of form.children) {
  child.required = true;
}
```

Please check the snippet below:

```js
function unlocking() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("check");
  var form = document.getElementById("unlock");

  if (checkBox.checked) {
    form.style.display = "block";
    for (child of form.children) {
      child.required = true;
      console.log(child);
    }
  } else {
    form.style.display = "none";
    for (child of form.children) {
      child.required = false;
      console.log(child);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checked" id="check" onclick="unlocking()" />
<label for="checkbox">If checked</label>
<fieldset id="unlock" style="display: none;">
  <input type="text" name="Name" value="Name" id="inside" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="email" id="inside" />
  <input type="text" name="Adress" value="Adress" id="inside" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This kinda works , if i refresh the page and click submit it doesn't work(fields requred),i need to check and uncheck the checkbox for fields not be required.Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer. All you have to do is remove the `required` attribute from the HTML elements. Please let me know if this solved your issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
//element.setAttribute("required", "");    turns required on
//element.removeAttribute("required");     turns required off


function unlocking() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("check")
    var form = document.getElementById("unlock")
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')

    if(checkBox.checked) {
       form.style.display="block";
       for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
       inputs[i].setAttribute("required", "");
    }else {
       form.style.display="none";
       for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
       inputs[i].removeAttribute("required");
    }
}
```